# how to list included bash functions?

Tags: bash, shell

Define a bash function `fname` in a file named *a.sh*:

```
fname(){
  echo "Foo"
}
```

We can include the function in this way:

> `source a.sh`

After that we can call the `fname` in the shell. I wonder if there is a way to display all the included functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list all the declared functions and the body, you can run :

```
set
```

or

```
declare -f
```

If you only want the functions names :

```
declare -f -F
```

or

```
declare -f -F | cut -d " " -f3
```

[Note that `typeset` is deprecated in 2013](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare)

And from http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete about `typeset` :

> This is closely related to the above, and should often be used
>   together. typeset exists primarily for ksh compatibility, but is
>   marked as "deprecated" in Bash (though I don't entirely agree with
>   this). This somewhat makes sense, because future compatibility can't
>   be guaranteed, and any compatibility at all requires understanding the
>   non-POSIX features of other shells and their differences. Using
>   declare instead of typeset emphasizes your intention to be
>   "bash-only", and definitely breaks everywhere else (except possibly
>   zsh if you're lucky). The issue is further complicated by Dash and the
>   Debian policy requirement for a local builtin, which is itself not
>   entirely compatible with Bash and other shells.

Comment: not really deprecated. I imagine it's listed that way to keep people that don't know what they're doing out of trouble. I've been meaning to update that page for quite a while.

Comment: Yes, that one's probably the more accurate description for now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

`typeset -f`

[Documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html) on `typeset`

Comment: This is ok. `-f` is one of the portable options with currently no conflicting usages. Provided you're aware of that, there's no problem. (I wrote most of that wiki page. Neglecting updating because it's a complex subject and there's a lot of missing / undocumented things to cover.)