# List bash functions and locations

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to get a list of functions and their locations (the file where the function is defined), that appear in `.bashrc` or any files sourced from there. E.g.

```
foo ~/.bashrc
bar ~/.bin/func.sh
```

The function names can be obtained via `declare`, but how about their locations? I've thought getting all the sourced files in `.bashrc` (e.g. using something like `egrep '^ *(\.)|(source) ' ~/.bashrc`) and then traversing `declare -F | cut -d' ' -f3` and look for each function in `.bashrc` and the sourced files. Is there a simpler way?

P.S. The are many other questions regarding listing functions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360822/how-to-list-included-bash-functions)) but they don't deal with locations.

Edit: I found the following in bash's man page:

> The -F option to declare or typeset will  list
>         the  function names only (and optionally the source file and line >number, if the extdebug shell option is enabled).

However `shopt -s extdebug && declare -F` doesn't list files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation does not clearly say that, but you need to call `declare -F` with a particular function as argument in order to obtain the file and line number of it's declaration. It can be done in a loop:

```
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ declare -F | while read foo bar fun ; do declare -F "$fun" ;done
$ shopt -u extdebug
```

Comment: Thx, for completeness sake, can you wrap the answer with `shopt -s extdebug` and `shopt -u extdebug`?